# Disjoint groups using maximum matching

Tags: sets, matching

In the 3-Path Packing problem, we are given an undirected graph $G$ and a parameter
$k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. We need to answer Yes/No if there exists a collection of $k$ vertex disjoint paths on three vertices in $G$.

I am interested in an easier variant of this problem where we are given an additional group $M \subseteq V$ that the middle vertex in each path is from $M$ and the adjacent nodes are not. So for any legal 3-path $u\rightarrow v \rightarrow x$, we should have $u,x \in V \setminus M$ and $v \in M$.

I am trying to find a polynomial algorithm for this problem by using maximum matching.

My solution is based on defining a vertex for any possible 3-path in the graph.
Since we are restricting ourselves to choose a middle vertex only from $M \subseteq V$ this can be done in polynomial time and space.

I am now trying to define the edges and extra nodes in a manner that will guarantee that nodes with common vertices cannot be picked together. But every time I am blocking or allowing legal/illegal choices.

This problem can also be represented as determining if there exist $k$ disjoint sets among a given group of size 3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any relation to [3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching)?

Comment: In the case where $k=|M|$, you can create a bipartite graph $(A \cup B, E)$ with $A=V\setminus M$, $B$ being two copies of $M$, and $E$ being (two copies of, one for each copy of $M$) only the edges between $V\setminus M$ and $M$: The answer is YES iff a perfect matching exists in this graph. I suspect it might be hard for other $k$.